# Bazel compilation with multiple compilers

Tags: bazel

I have a very simple test case with the following structure:

```
project
   |
   |-- app
   |    |
   |    |-- BUILD
   |    |-- *.cpp *.h
   |
   |-- lib
   |    |
   |    |-- BUILD
   |    |-- *.cpp *.h
   |
   |-- WORKSPACE
```

The `app` contains a `cc_binary` rule, while the `lib` -- only `cc_library` that is compiled into a shared library and linked to the executable.

The issue that I have is that I need to compile `lib` with `gcc-9`, while `app` -- with `gcc-10`.

I tried to create custom toolchains following [this](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/tutorial/cc-toolchain-config.html) article from the documentation. However, as far as I can understand, it is applied to the global code, and not particular targets.

I have also found that `toolchains` can be specified in a building target rule, e.g.:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "main",
    srcs = ["main.cpp"],
    deps = [
        "//lib:cpplib"
    ],
    toolchains = [
        "//toolchain:gcc10_toolchain"
    ]
)
```

However, this usage is incorrect and gives the following error: `in toolchains attribute of cc_binary rule //app:main: '//toolchain:gcc10_toolchain' does not have mandatory providers: 'TemplateVariableInfo'`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Kinda wonder if you ever got it to work. If so, how?
2. I met a similar problem (not the same) but got around with non-graceful way maybe it can provide something (or not)

My scenario is that I need to integrate CUDA code (nvcc) into existing C++ library (using clang-8).

So I know that bazel lets you use bash script to mimic what a real compiler. So in crosstool.bzl, at the place of "gcc", instead of using the original entry in the existing codebase ("/usr/bin/clang"), I changed it to the path to my bash script

```
tool_paths = [
    ...
    tool_path = (name="gcc", path="PATH_TO_MY_BASH_SCRIPT.sh"),
    ...
]
```

You need to define flags/options to differentiate one lib/bin needing one compiler from another. For me I use `cuda` as an diff copt for the libs that needs nvcc while all the others needing clang being without `cuda` in copts

In the bash, you can define how you wanna call the compiler, based on compilation options and flags. Or you can define a personal python script that calls corresponding compilers based on flags and options, and let the bash call python to execute your python script (the compiler wrapper) like

```
python $PATH_TO_COMPILER_WRAPPER.py "$@"
```

This helped me get through but apparently itself looks like a rabbit hole . If you ever solved your problem in a graceful manner, please let me know. thnx